# print values one by one in tcl

Tags: tcl, informix

I have the following code in tcl ..

```
proc GetPPVSummary {} {
    global LIBRARY DB_MACHINE ALT_MACHINE

    set query "SELECT first 2 * from test ORDER by ppv_id DESC"
    set result [mtlrequest $LIBRARY DbSelect "test@$ALT_MACHINE|$query"]

    return $result
}

set return_data [GetPPVSummary]
puts $return_data
```

the above returns something like this:

> {{753 38 {2000-04-10 00:00:00} {2000-04-11 00:00:00} 3 HQAWR 56897 PPV B Event_04292012_teaser {} Event_04292012_teaser The_World_Doesnt_Care {$99.00} {$0.01}}

How do I print only the values one by one in tcl?

ok so i tried the following now:

```
foreach record $return_data {
    set event_date [lindex $record 1]
    set attempts_cnt [lindex $record 2]
    set success_cnt [lindex $record 3]
    set fail_cnt [lindex $record 4]
}


puts $event_date
```

Now, i get the whole full row instead of the first or second value..

Comment: there's one more open brace than close braces. Is this exactly your data?

Comment: @glennjackman, I noticed that too, but decided this was a copy & paste error.  Now I'm trying to get the real rowset in the comment thread under my answer to this question--feel free to join the forces ;-)

Comment: @user856753, what output do you want to see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming $return_data is a list of lists, you want

```
foreach record $return_data {
    foreach item $record {
        puts $item
    }
}
```

Comment: 752 2003 {2012-04-23 00:00:00} {2012-04-29 20:30:00} 1 10017 10018 PPV B Event_04292012_teaser {} Event_04292012_HD_price {} {} {}  is what my data is

Comment: ok glenn's solution almost worked but it doesnt let me store it in a variable and display one by one...so I am going to create a new question based on the results of my new query. I hope I make myself clear this time..sorry for all the confusion!

Answer (score 2):

Most probably `mtlrequest` returns a list so if by "How do I print only the values one by one in tcl?" you wanted to ask "how do I extract members from this value", there are several possible answers:

- [`lindex`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/lindex.htm) can be used to extract a member of a list by its numerical index, like `set x [lindex $return_data 5]` would set variable "x" to the value `HQAWR`.
- [`lassign`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/lassign.htm) (Tcl 8.5+) can be used to assign elements of a list value to a set of variables, like `lassign $return_data a b c d ...`

Note that those `{`s and `}` have no special meaning—they are the result of Tcl converting the list value to a string (you asked it to do so by using `puts`): see [this](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl4.html) and [this](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl14.html) parts of [the tutorial](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html) for explanations.

Working yourself through the whole tutorial is highly advised, otherwise you'll be banging your head against every tiny problem.  Tcl is way more simpler than it may appear at first sight, so just take your time and master its basics.

Comment: i saw the tutorial and tried to add some code.see my edited question..but I still dont see the desired result.

Comment: OK, can you post the result of `puts $return_data` for your select query which returns, say, 10 rows (not just 2 as in your initial examlpe), to something like http://pastebin.com ?  Lest we're doomed to do perpetual guesseneering.

Comment: We're going in circles, it seems. Are you really sure what you pasted is really the result of selecting *several* rows from the database?  To me, it looks like one row: each element of this list apparently has different data type while *in a rowset,* there should be several rows where the value in each column has the same data type.